# Signature Invalid for yodlee

Tags: signature, yodlee, method-signature

Using token,token secret,Consumer key,Consumer secret,time-stamp,nonce i generate the signature using developer account but it always shows the Signature invalid while connect the fast link of yodlee, May be the generated signature method wrong, Can any one provide the Lib's for generating signature using java.

Comment: dude, this whole thing is one sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please provide the request you are generating? Meanwhile, can you please take a look at integration guide present [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Yodlee_FastLink_and_LAW_Guide/Yodlee_FastLink_Integration_Guide).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Apoorv for your replay.

The below url i generated                                                                                                                                                                             https://fastlink.yodlee.com/appscenter/fastlinksb/linkAccount.fastlinksb.action?access_type=oauthdeeplink&displayMode=desktop&oauth_callback=http://www.google.com&oauth_consumer_key=XXXXXXX&oauth_nonce=her1lk40NpL&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1407732923&oauth_token=9819d4247f9f44959510832bc6688b86&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=IRVbo09jAub0FTtt7uLMPA==

please verify this and letme know what is the mistaken

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this as well after looking at the oAuth 1.0 sample code. If you enter your callback url without the protocol it will work. In your case just enter www.google.com. When you need the protocol you must url encode the querystring parameter.

https://fastlink.yodlee.com/appscenter/fastlinksb/linkAccount.fastlinksb.action?access_type=oauthdeeplink&displayMode=desktop&oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&oauth_consumer_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&oauth_nonce=6238157&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1407996476&oauth_token=11232e9a123111111d8a19175663ecd947&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=4RbNDY9z1wC/vMV5neitQa7ZxQM=

Answer (score 0):

While generating the signature you also need to include the URL and parameters. You can find libraries on JAVA for generating signature at [Oauth JAVA](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/)

Also if you want to invoke the FastLink in a browser for testing then you can use steps from this [article](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Yodlee_FastLink_and_LAW_Guide/Yodlee_FastLink_Integration_Guide#Steps_for_Invoking_Yodlee_FastLink)